# Web view in React native seems to be slower

Tags: react-native, webview, progressive-web-apps

please forgive my bad English. I have a react native app and I have to load a PWA application through WebView in React native. My website is only taking about 5 sec to load in the browser. But when it comes to React Native, after the launch screen and Splash screen it is taking more than 15 sec to load the content. Please help me to fix the same. Any input is valuable and appreciative

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.